# Can't sign in to a Google account using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, authentication, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I try to log into a Google account using Selenium, it says verify it's you, but if I go back and enter the account credentials manually, I log in without any problems. So it's not a problem with my ip or a running chromedriver. [Process gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqFze.gif)

```
        WebDriverWait(self, 15).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="email"]')
            )
        ).send_keys(email)
        self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[id="identifierNext"]').click()

        WebDriverWait(self, 15).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="password"]')
            )
        ).send_keys(password)
        self.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[id="passwordNext"]').click()
```

I've tried to use Actions move_to_element and then click, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Add some error logs which will help to give your question's answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.